# how to achieve word wrap effect that stackoverflow has in preview box

Tags: jquery, css

I have a preview box much like the one stackoverflow uses, for submitting material that updates in real time. The problem is that a really long word hangs on the outside. Does stackoverflow use a jquery plugin to wrap long words in the preview box or a css rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StackOverflow uses WMD ([blog article on the reverse engineering effort](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/wmd-editor-reverse-engineered/)), which includes the preview.  The code for it is freely available on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/).  Even if you don't want to use the editor you could look at the code to see how it is done.

Comment: so this basically changes default css rules and form behavior, and modifies them with one set of behavior?

Answer (score 2):

It's just CSS:

```
#wmd-preview p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: why was javascript used to invoke the rules then? Why not just create one large css doc?

Comment: This CSS instruction is as magic as is Supercalifragilisticexpialidoceous, especially for WCAG2 and its requirement of a 200% zoom text.